# как считывать события с клавиатуры

Tags: java

У меня есть консольная файловая система, хочу добавить команду отменить последнее действие, решил что надо создать обработчик событий который считывает нажатие ENTER и тогда событие записывается в структуру данных как стек, не знаю как реализовать

вот над чем остановился

```
private final int ENTER = 13;
private boolean KEY_PRESSED;

private void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if (e.getKeyCode() == ENTER){
        KEY_PRESSED = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Stack<KeyEvent> keyEvents=new Stack<KeyEvent>(); 

private void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if (e.getKeyCode() == ENTER){
        keyEvents.push(e);  //помещаем событие в стек
    }
}
```

Comment: не знаю как само событие перемещать в стек, идет вроде file.createNewFile(), как это событие перенести в коллекцию?